# how to send socket.io data to the specific client using socket.userId

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm a new member of socket.io. I'm using elephant.io and socket.io, I need to send some notification data to a specific client. but I can't use a socket.Id is autogenerated id, I need to use my user id, so how can I send the data please give me a server-side and client-side.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to emit a data socket.userid but it not working, but socket.on broadcast working. it sending data to all clients, but I need to use socket.userid, i cant use socket.id its resting always

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to have a different event listener for every room then emit something like `message_${room_id}`.

Since you haven't provided any reference code the following code may not be specific to your use-case and will require adjusting.

backend-server.js

```js
// Define variables
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server); 

// room_id generator
function makeid(length) {
    let result = '';
    let characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

app.get('/request-room', function(req, res) { // Listen for the incoming request to /request/room
    let room_id = makeid(20); // Generate a roomID 20 characters long
    res.redirect('/rooms/' + room_id); // Redirect the user to the room
});
app.get('/rooms/:roomId', function(req, res) { // Listen for the incomign request to a random room
    io.emit(`message_${req.params.roomId}`, { message: 'A user has joined your room!' }); // Emits to the room that a user has joined
    // Send the user some sort of HTML page
});

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is online');
```

Then in your HTML file, listen for the message

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <!-- Some HTML script -->
</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- Import socket.io -->
<script>
    let socket = io.connect(); // Connect to the server
    let room_id = (window.location.href).split('/')[(window.location.href).split('/').length - 1]; // Get the last param in the URL
    socket.on(`message_${room_id}`, function(data) { // Listen for the message specific to the room
        // Do something with the data
    });
</script>
```